# Vue maintain route params on page refersh

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, router

I want to be able to pass list of meta/props to multiple components based on the route. To achieve this I am doing following. The todo list is hardcoded. Which is how I want. it is NOT dynamically loaded. 
my solution only works if I click from list to go to item. However if I try to navigate directly / refresh the page. I am losing the `meta` param.

Question is how can I maintain this on page refresh? Is there a better approach to managing this?

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-router-3oblk

```
// todo.vue
<template>
  <div class="todos">
    <h1>Todos</h1>
    <stats :value="total" label="Total"></stats>
    <stats :value="completed" label="Completed"></stats>
    <stats :value="pending" label="Pending"></stats>
    <todo-list :todos="todos"></todo-list>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Stats from "../components/Stats";
import TodoList from "../components/TodoList";

export default {
  name: "Home",
  components: {
    "todo-list": TodoList,
    stats: Stats
  },
  data() {
    return {
      limit: 20,
      todos: [
        {
          userId: 1,
          id: 1,
          title: "delectus aut autem",
          completed: false
        },
        {
          userId: 1,
          id: 2,
          title: "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
          completed: false
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  computed: {
    total: function() {
      return this.todos.length;
    },
    completed: function() {
      return this.todos.filter(function(todo) {
        return todo.completed === true;
      }).length;
    },
    pending: function() {
      return this.todos.filter(function(todo) {
        return todo.completed === false;
      }).length;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

```
// todo list
<template>
  <ul v-if="todos.length > 0">
    <li v-for="todo in todos" :key="todo.id">
      <router-link :to="{name: 'singletodo', params: {id: todo.id, meta: todo}}">
        <span :class="todo.completed ? 'completed' : ''">{{ todo.title }}</span>
      </router-link>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "TodoList",
  props: ["todos"]
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.completed {
  color: gray;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

ul {
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-left: 1em;
}

li {
  list-style: square;
}
</style>
```

```
// Router config
const routes = [
  { path: "/", name: "home", component: Home },
  { path: "/about", name: "about", component: About },
  { path: "/todos", name: "todo", component: Todos },
  { path: "/todos/:id", name: "singletodo", component: TodoSingle }
];

const router = new Router({
  routes
});
```

Comment: Need to see your router config.  My first guess is you didn't define the parameters as part of the path

Comment: @Trevor I've updated the question. I also added codesandbox.io link

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot get the data on refresh without handling it dynamically (using a state management library like Vuex for example). In that way when you are in the singletodo route you can retrieve the todo from the global state by getting the id param

Comment: @SylvainF A page refresh erases vuex as well. It would need to be stored to more permanent storage.

Answer (score 1):

Update your routes like this

```
// Router config
const routes = [
  { path: "/", name: "home", component: Home },
  { path: "/about", name: "about", component: About },
  { path: "/todos", name: "todo", component: Todos },
  { path: "/todos/:id/:meta?", name: "singletodo", component: TodoSingle }
];
```

This adds the meta parameter to the URL as optional.  Remove the ? to make it required.  You need this to allow page refreshes.